# Angular JS got javascript message error: Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to fix the problem, when javascript error message "Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1" . When i tried to implementing     [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/getting-started)

Comment: provide some more codes?

Comment: explain your full issue?

Comment: It could be a lot of reasons. At least provide some code please

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lot of things. Like : your function is not defined, your function needs dependencies witch are not loaded yet (hapenend when you include your scripts in the bad order in your html file), etc..